# Is wrong to use e.preventDefault () if the event is on the id of an element and not on a "generic" tags?

Tags: javascript, preventdefault

if i have an event on specific `id` is right or wrong to use `e.preventDefault()` ?

Example:

```
document.getElementById("googleMap").addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var touch = e.touches[0];
 if(e.touches.length == 2){
  map.setOptions({draggable:true});
 }
});
```

In this case maybe is wrong no ? because i have only one element with id `googleMap`

But is correct to use for example in this case:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

??

(really for me is not clear when use `e.preventDefault()`)...

Please sorry for my english and thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

No, it's perfectly fine to use `e.preventDefault()` on your `googleMap` object.

The event listener is on a DOM element.  It doesn't matter how you found that DOM element whether you used an ID, a tag, a class or some other method.

`ocument.getElementById("googleMap")` returns a DOM element.  Once you have the reference to the DOM element, it doens't matter how you found it.  It's a reference to the DOM element no matter how it was found.

---

One thing you do have to be careful of with `e.preventDefault()` is that some events propagate up the chain and if you are intercepting the event part way up the chain, the event may have already been processed lower in the chain, defeating some of what you're trying to prevent.  So, if you want total control over what happens with the event, you may have to capture the event at the lowest level (at the original object the event is targeted at).

---

The purpose of `e.preventDefault()` is to prevent a default action that the browser has assigned to whatever event is occurring.  For example, the default action when clicking on a link in the browser is to follow the href of that link and load a new page with that URL.  If you want the click on the link to NOT follow the link, but to instead handle the click in your Javascript and do something different, then you call `e.preventDefault()`.  If you don't prevent the default, then the browser will carry out the default action for that event after your event handler runs.

If there is no default action for an event or if you are not trying to prevent the default action, then do not call it.  In general, you would only use `e.preventDefault()` when the browser is executing some default action that you don't want it to execute.  Otherwise, leave it out of your code.  If your code is working fine without `e.preventDefault()`, then do not add it as it will not be needed in that circumstance.

Comment: ok but what changes if there's or not  e.preventDefault() ?  i'm not understanding :(

Comment: @MatisLepik i'm here to have help and understand how works... sorry but your comment don'have sense

Comment: @Borja - I added a paragraph to my answer that explains `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: ok @jfriend00 now i understand how works (and i thank you) but now i have a small doubt.... why my code (first example) works ? the map of google is not draggable if i "touchmove" with two fingers (e.touches.length == 2), but in function there's e.preventDefault

Answer (score 0):

event.preventDefault() simply stops event default mechanism. So it is safe to use in any event listener irrespective of id, class or any other selector.

Comment: but what does mean with "event default mechanism" in this example ?

Comment: lets say u add a keypress event and you pressed key 's'. Ideal behaviour is your input would have letter 's' now. but if you do event.preventDefault() 
then your input wont get the letter 's'.

Comment: ok but so why in my example the event "touchmove" work also if is there e.preventDefault ??????????